# Hive - Join on map data type column

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

```
 table 1 - 

    name bal map<String,String> year   

    abc 24000   {car : honda, company : boa} 2015
    ac 21000  { car:honda} 2015
    def 23000 {car:honda, company: boa} 2015
    abc 21000   {car : honda, company : boa} 2014
    ac 20000  { car:honda} 2014
    def 22000 {car:honda, company: boa} 2014

        Required Output after self join -  

        name bal-difference map<String,String> 
        abc 3000 {car : honda, company : boa} 
        ac 1000 { car:honda} 
        def 1000 {car:honda, company: boa} 



    select 
    t1.name,t1.mapColumn,(t1.bal-t2.bal)
    FROM  table1 t1 JOIN table1 t2 
    ON t1.mapColumn = t2.mapColumn and t1.name = t2.name
```

I want to perform self join on table on map column and name in hive. So that i can perform difference of balance as seen in example output.

I tried join but it is not giving required columns. I want to understand how join works on complex datatypes(in my case map).

Comment: What do you have done exaclty? What do you mean by "is not giving required columns", i.e. what is it missing?

Comment: @mark91 Updated with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView

You have to use LATER VIEW EXPLODE syntax to expose nested map and use it in JOINs.

Answer (score 0):

As of now in hive we cannot join on map datatypes, if you know all the keys of mapcolumn beforehand. you can key in all the keys as t1.mapColumn['car'] = t2.mapColumn['car'] and etc.. otherwise try using below:

```
select t1.name ,t1.mapColumn ,(t1.bal - t2.bal)
FROM (select * from table1 where tran_year = '2015') t1 
JOIN (select * from table1 where tran_year = '2014') t2 
ON    map_keys(t1.mapColumn) <=> map_keys(t2.mapColumn)  
and   map_values(t1.mapColumn) <=> map_values(t2.mapColumn)
and   t1.name = t2.name;
```

you can use lateral views to explode into multiple rows but you will have trouble finding the difference between the bal as there will multiple rows with same bal.

`<=>` operator will Returns same result with EQUAL`=` operator for non-null operands, but returns TRUE if both are NULL, FALSE if one of the them is NULL

Comment: But key in map is not know well before, I want query to handle everything.

Comment: I updated the answer, please check if it resolves your concerns.